# Acrylic brush opacity when not in focus

Tags: uwp

Id like to keep the acrylic/opacity effect of my grids background when the app looses focus. By default it goes to the fallback color which is a solid color.
How would i make this transparent ?

My current acrylic brush is as follows

```xml
<media:AcrylicBrush x:Key="HostBackdropBrush"
                           BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop"
                           TintColor="LightBlue"
                           TintOpacity="0.6"
                           FallbackColor="LightSkyBlue"/>
```

I am trying to set this as the effect for the whole application like how CMD keeps its transparency even with it unfocused. I would like the blur/acrylic effect though not transparent.

Answer (score 1):

Acutually you can’t keep acrylic while the application is not focused. Because once the uwp app goes to background it will enter battery saving option. Utilizing acrylic or reveal highlight uses GPU for processing which is power intensive. So it wont accept providing acrylic in background.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting FallbackColor to Transparent, or if you still want a colour use the RGBA values with an alpha channel set so it's barely visible

Comment: I am unable to find anything on the internet to help me do either of these things. the fallback color is hex, if i change the opacity of the fallback color it doesnt make a difference

Answer (score 0):

@Vignesh's suggestion was on correct direction. Please check [Usability and adaptability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/acrylic#usability-and-adaptability) to know more information.

If the background acrylic is the only one option for you, there's no other way for you. Because the document has explained that this behavior is by design.

If you accept to use the in-app acrylic, then you could avoid this behavior. The in-app acrylic will not be affected when an app window on desktop deactivates.

```
<media:AcrylicBrush x:Key="BackdropBrush"
                       BackgroundSource="Backdrop"
                       TintColor="LightBlue"
                       TintOpacity="0.6"
                       FallbackColor="LightSkyBlue"/>
```